# Copy drop down list from excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can i copy a entire drop down list from excel 2007 one document to another excel document, i have tried copying and pasting special, some forms told me to copy it through data validation process but it doesn't work.

Comment: What kind of dropdown are we talking about here? Can you provide a screenshot? In what way did you try copying it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the form is referencing a data validation process, I'm assuming you're talking about a cell drop-down that is the result of data validation.

The set of values you see in the drop down comes from a source - either cells in a worksheet, or a custom list or formula.

To see what, click on the cell, go to data validation (either in the ribbon or in the data menu), and check what validation criteria are present. If the criteria are from cells, you can navigate to those cells and copy them directly. If it's a custom list or formula, it should show up here also. You can copy by selecting in this window.

Answer (score 0):

click on Data Validation as it state above.  You can then edit that field or change the parameters to add more drop down options.  Copy this block of cells into your new spreadsheet, taking note of their new location and you should be good to go!

Comment: The OP is saying that using the Data Validation Process doesn't work; can you describe why clicking on it would work, as you describe in your solution?